# Double Free/Abort Trap/Seg. Fault troubles

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've been having troubles with my c program. When trying to insert into an array from multiple threads, I keep randomly (I'll explain) running into Abort Traps and Seg. Faults.

By random I mean it'll run through to completion sometimes, and other times I'll get Double Free, and occasionally I'll get Seg. Faults.

```
void insertIntoFinalArray(char * string) {
    sem_wait(&insert);
    printf("%d\n", sem_getvalue(&insert, 0));
    if (finalarray == NULL) finalarray = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *));
    else finalarray = (char **) realloc(finalarray, ((size_final + 1) * sizeof(char *)));

    finalarray[size_final] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(string) + 1);
    strcpy(finalarray[size_final], string);
    //printf("%s\n", finalarray[size_final]);
    size_final++;
    sem_post(&insert);
}
```

final array is declared as a global var `char ** finalarray;`

Comment: What RTOS are you using? Are you sure that sem_wait/sem_post is the appropriate thread-safe functions for this RTOS and processor?

Comment: @MarkLakata I'm required by my assignment specs. to use semaphores. I'm not quite sure which RTOS I'm using/exactly what it is. I'm running on OS X.

Comment: what line is causing the crash?

Comment: are you sure that finalarray = NULL and size_final=0 at startup?

Comment: @MarkLakata I just added finalarray = NULL at initialization, and no luck.

Comment: @MarkLakata additionally, I haven't been able to get gdb working on my system, so I have no idea. It enters the function, prints the value of the semaphore, and then either seg. faults or Abort Traps

Comment: Why don't you use Xcode instead of gcc/gdb? It's free.

Comment: @MarkLakata honestly I just don't like the editor. But I'll give it a shot - I need a debugger, it seems.